# Best function value for Expected Improvement computation for Gaussian Process Regression

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, gaussian-process, bayesian-optimization, active-learning

I want to implement Gaussian Process regression in the context of active learning, in which interpolation is performed with the best interpolating points, selected at each step iteratively. At every step, the subsequent sample to query is selected in such a way as to maximize an acquisition function, i.e., Expected Improvement. To compute it, the "current best function value" is needed. My question is: can we consider that value as the value given by the user to the last queried sample?

Comment: is your problem noiseless?

Comment: Can't be considered this way, because it is a sort of fast interpolation of the contralateral equal loudness contour. It is a regression method for determining a perceptual problem, so it can't be considered noiseless, but the noise level must be set more or less arbitrarily.

Comment: I see, getting a Best Observed Function Value (BOFV) is harder in the noisy case: we need to use our surrogate to estimate this. Most commonly, we take the minimum of the predictive mean surface at previously evaluated points.

Comment: Thank you for answering, because you arrived at the core of my doubts. Why should we take the minimum? I mean: what makes the minimum of the mean the best approximation of the "latent" function?

Comment: I think we should first clear up what we're estimating here. Let's say we are trying to minimize a stochastic function $f$, and denote the true mean at a point $x$ as $\mu(x)$ and standard dev as $\sigma(x)$. EI is defined mathematically as $ei(x) = \mathbb{E}[(\underset{x_n\in \{x_1,\ldots,x_N\}}{\min} \mu(x_n)-\mu(x))^+]$; intuitively, for a given point $x$, we want to measure how much the mean value at this candidate point is below the mean value at the best of the points we've measured. "How much better is this candidate point on average relative to the best point I have so far?".

Comment: (there's a couple different notions of "mean value" floating around; the "average" that $\mu$ is taking is with respect to different realizations of your stochastic simulator evaluated at the same point, whereas the (outer) "expectation" from "expected improvement" is with respect to the (bayesian) uncertainty of the GP model.).

Comment: Yes, I think I have understood that: there are the average and the variance of the Gaussian Process computed at every point, and the mean of the expected value of the improvement given by the sample to query, selected from a certain pool of candidates. But the assumption "Let's say we are trying to minimize a stochastic function" is not valid in my case. In the active learning framework, the user is not minimizing it, is determining it. That is why I don't understand why taking the minimum should be valuable. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Hmm, I suspect there is some confusion. The body of your post says you are conducting Bayesian optimization, but in this last comment it sounds like you're just trying to best estimate a function. Can you clarify what your goals are?

Comment: I am estimating a function, with a limited number of interpolating points. I start with a GP prior; with its mean and variance an acquisition function is computed to determine the next point to query. The user provides the value for the queried sample, hence an additional interpolating point. And so on, iteratively, for some iterations. I have done that with the sample randomly selected among the points where the variance is more than 90% of its maximum. I would like to use the Expected Improvement instead of that acquisition function, but I am stuck on what is the BOFV in this context.

Comment: ye expected improvement is explicitly for optimization, which it does not sound like you are doing (may be worth editing the body of your post to remove the reference to Bayesian optimization). There are a few approaches to sequential design where the aim is to better understand the function. I like the "Integrated Mean Square Prediction Error" IMSPE criterion (see section 4 of https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11222-011-9242-3), but it's a bit mathy if youre not comfortable with that. The simplest approach would be to acquire where you have the highest predictive variance.

Comment: Thank you very much for the patience and the reference. The simplest approach you pointed out is the one that I already implemented. Then I tried to play around with more complex approaches: I tried to reduce the variance by subtracting the likelihood from it, kind of having samples where the models is uncertain of its prediction but sure of its parameters. Is that making any sense? I'll read the reference and formulate the question more properly.

Comment: The variance approach is very similar, but somewhat different (and who knows how big the gap might be in practice between the two): I'm suggesting literally finding the single point with the highest predictive variance (there could be many in high dimension). I'm not sure what you mean by subtracting likelihood, unfortunately.

Comment: I am finding the best approximating Gaussian process with the maximization of the log-likelihood. When the log-likelihood is maximized, I find the GP, its mean and variance at every point of the pool of samples to query. Instead of using just the variance, for what I have understood I think the likelihood is giving me the information of how much the model is certain about its parameters. So subtracting it from the variance, is penalizing points where the model is sure about itself, while adding it should privilege those points. Does it make any sense to you?

Comment: I'm just confused, because the likelihood is a function of your kernel hyperparameters and is parameterized by your observed data: I don't see where the new candidate points would fit in. (Also, use this reference instead for IMSPE if you're interested: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.03206.pdf; other one is not what I thought it was)

Comment: I started to read your reference, but there is a major difference: in that study, they consider replication, and they consider computer simulations. In my case, I would like to have the interpolation points to be considered just once, and the problem is more related to which location is better to consider the consequent point. I'll reformulate the problem in another question. Thank you!

Comment: I wrote you, you can remove your email if you mind. Thank you!